# Indent list bullet and add space between bullet and text

Tags: lists, indentation

I am using this snippet to make list with default document line interval and it also indents only first line.

```
% Compact list
\newenvironment{compactlist}{
 \begin{list}{{$\bullet$}}{
  \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
  \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
  \setlength{\itemindent}{\leftmargin}
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}
 }
}{
 \end{list}
}
```

But it indents text to default indentation level. How can I set up two horizontal spaces: between left margin and bullet (1.25cm), and between bullet and text (0.63cm)?

update:

```
\usepackage{indentfirst}
%\setlength{\parindent}{1.25cm} %uncomment to break indentation
```

Looks like I need first to make lists respect indentadion level which was set for \parindent.

[image: list_indentation]

```
\documentclass[oneside,draft,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\setpapersize{A4}
\fussy
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{indentfirst}
%\setlength{\parindent}{1.25cm} %uncomment to break indentation

% List with default line intervals
\newenvironment{compactlist}{
 \begin{list}{{$\bullet$}}{
  \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
  \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
  \setlength{\itemindent}{\leftmargin}
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}
 }
}{
 \end{list}
}

\begin{document}

In 1778, John Parke Custis purchased an 1,100-acre (450 ha) tract of
forested land on the Potomac River north of the town of Alexandria,
Virginia.

\begin{compactlist}
 \item This land became the Arlington Estate. John Custis died in
September 1781, and in 1799 his son, George Washington Parke Custis
("G.W.P.") step-grandson of George Washingto inherited the site. G.W.P
Custis and his wife, Mary, moved onto the estate, and between 1802 and
1814 they constructed Arlington House;
 \item The Custises extensively developed the site.
\end{compactlist}

Much of the steep slope to the east of the house
became a cultivated English landscape park, while a large flower
garden with an arbor was constructed and planted south of the house.

\end{document}
```

Comment: See your previous question: [Indent first line only in customized list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56196) and I recommend to use `enumitem`

Comment: Actually I used that solution, but I have different indentaion, not one like on *locktep screenshot.

Comment: In this case -- Please provide a MWE and not only a snippet.

Comment: Hm, does it means that it already should be indented like I am asking it this post? I'll try to figure out what can break indentation.

Comment: Please look at update - posted gist with MWE.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`enumitem` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) is your most convenient option here:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\begin{document}
\noindent Here is some text.
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,labelindent=12.5mm,labelsep=6.3mm]
  \item Here is some text.
  \item Here is some text.
\end{itemize}
\noindent \rule{12.5mm}{1pt}$\bullet$\rule{6.3mm}{1pt} \par
\noindent Here is some text.
\end{document}
```

Setting the `leftmargin` flush with the left margin (via `*`), leaves you to manually set `labelindent` (space between left margin and bullet) and `labelsep` (space between bullet and text).

The generalize these settings (and not have to set it locally via the optional argument), you can use

```
\setlist[itemize,1]{leftmargin=*,labelindent=12.5mm,labelsep=6.3mm}
```

which sets the first level of `itemize` to have the required layout. You can also create your own list using `\newlist`. See section **7 Cloning the basic lists** (p 10) in the [`enumitem` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf).

To add vertical spacing between items in the list, modify the `itemsep` property. Here's the above MWE with such a modification:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\setlist[itemize,1]{leftmargin=*,labelindent=12.5mm,labelsep=6.3mm,itemsep=2\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\noindent Here is some text.
\begin{itemize}
  \item Here is some text.
  \item Here is some text.
\end{itemize}
\noindent \rule{12.5mm}{1pt}$\bullet$\rule{6.3mm}{1pt} \par
\noindent Here is some text.
\end{document}
```

Other vertical spacing properties include `topsep`, `partopsep` and `parsep`. The [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf), again, includes descriptions on their impact.

The bottom row with rules in the above MWE is just to verify the lengths between the list elements.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to add kind of short alias for `\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,labelindent=12.5mm,labelsep=6.3mm]` ?

Comment: By the way, how can I set line interval for these lists? Like `onehalfspacing` (or better pick line interval from document environment)?

Comment: @dig: Yes, you can add some shorthand; I'll update my answer. Vertical separation between items are set using `itemsep`.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up with solution based on my code because I still have issues with line spacing and second line indentation with package @Werner adviced. And also this looks simplier (I had to add just two line to my snippet from original post).

```
% Compact list (assuming paragraph indent is 1.25cm)
\newenvironment{compactlist}{
 \begin{list}{{$\bullet$}}{
  \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
  \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
  \setlength{\labelsep}{0.63cm} % horizontal space from bullet to text (as needed)
  \setlength{\itemindent}{2.13cm} % summary indentation: par 1.25cm + bullet 0.63 + magic number picked empirically (0.25cm)
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt} % reset margin so that only first line of list item indented
 }
}{
 \end{list}
}
```

Comment: Although this might be down to personal preference, but I don't see this as being simpler necessarily. I *also* just added two lines of code *and* [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) allows for local modification of lists via an optional argument.

Comment: I think your solution is more solid, I'll revisit it one day :)