# Horizontal space between bullets and text in enumerate

Tags: spacing, enumerate, enumitem, bullets, horizontal

I have several enumerated lists. The bullets and the paragraph are too close, in my opinion, so I want to be able to make more white space between the bullet itself and the text that comes after, but I don't want to do it for every list I've made. I want to do it globally, in the preamble.

I believe the thing I want to do is described in here: [Indent list bullet and add space between bullet and text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56246/indent-list-bullet-and-add-space-between-bullet-and-text)
but I don't understand what I should do.

Can someone help me understand what the example in the link suggests I should do?

I am using all the necessary packages including the `enumitem` package.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: since you use the `enumitem` package, it has sense to read its documentation. there are explained all its options including how to change default spacing of labels' (bullets') space and left margin. for easer understanding description see http://texblog.net/latex-beginners-guide/examples/chapter-4/#list-layout, where is illustrated list structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how to do it with an enumerated list (not a bulleted), using the enumitem keys: we change the value of `\labelsep` and set `leftmargin=*` so the multilined item contents be left-aligned on the beginning of the first line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*., labelsep=1.5em, leftmargin=*]%
\item Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
\item Another text. 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can set these parameters globally for all `enumerate` environments in the preamble with

```
 \setlist[enumerate]{label=\arabic*., labelsep=1.5em, leftmargin=*}
```

or, if you want to set them only for the first level `enumerate`:

```
 \setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\arabic*., labelsep=1.5em, leftmargin=*}
```