# indent only first line in customized enumerate

Tags: indentation, enumerate

As I enumerate huge blocks of words, Latex automatically indents the entire paragraph. To save some space I want Latex to indent only the first line and leave the rest with full width.

[Indent first line only in customized list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56196/indent-first-line-only-in-customized-list) is exactly the same, but author uses list instead of enumeration and \bullet instead of \arabic. I tried to follow its pattern and tried different options, changing {list} to {enumerate}, \bullet to \arabic, etc. but no success. Can somebody please help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlist[enumerate]{itemindent=\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep\relax,leftmargin=0pt}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[4]
\item \lipsum[4]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As **Harish Kumar** mentions in [`his comment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268609/indent-only-first-line-in-customized-enumerate/268610?noredirect=1#comment644690_268610), the `wide` key can also be used:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlist[enumerate]{wide=\parindent}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[4]
\item \lipsum[4]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @HarishKumar Thanks. I added this option too.

Comment: Another question... Is it possible to apply this rule only for the first level of enumeration, which is "arabic" enumeration (1),(2),(3) etc, but not for the second level of enumeration, which is "alpha" (a),(b),(c)?
Because now both first and second levels have the same indentation space.

Comment: @Nur Sure: `\setlist[enumerate,1]{wide=\parindent}`. or similar for the other option, add a `1` in the optional argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I have something like this http://postimg.org/image/ftb1rbyjj/ I need to move the second level to the right. Can you kindly help me to do this?

Comment: @Nur And which option, from the two I gave are you using?

Comment: @Nur Something like this `\setlist[enumerate,2]{leftmargin=6em}` should work (replace `6em` conveniently).

Comment: Thanks a lot Gonzalo, now thats exactly what I need. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Excuse me for commenting a very old post, but I have a very similar problem ! I want to Indent only the 3 first lines in an enumerate or itemize mode, by 10 or 15 mm, because of my needs ( I want to fill the 3 first lines by a box or a small image or something like that).. Can you tell me about that if it looks simple for you !? Many thanks

Comment: I can do this task by using something like 

`\newcommand\litem[1]{\item[]{\hspace{5mm} $\bullet$ #1 }}`

use `\litem` for the first item and play with `\phantom` for the second line if any, but I think that it's inelegant, and not stable. Any idea using the package enumitem, or other ?